# Unique design inside a specific category's url

Tags: theme-development, filters, templates, design

I been modifying a WordPress theme, and for some specific pages that need a specific design I placed a php file named `page-specific-url.php` where specific-url is the page I want to show.

The problem I am facing is the location of the specific page I need to design is inside of of a category so the url is `domain.com/category1/specific-page`. How can I add the extra category1 so when I placed the `specific-page.php` in the root of the theme I can access it through `domain.com/category1/specific-page`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a filter called [`theme_page_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) which you can use to force the use of a certain template under certain circumstances. Like this:

```
add_filter ('theme_page_templates', 'wpse263827_filter_theme_page_templates', 20, 3 );
wpse263827_filter_theme_page_templates ($page_templates, $this, $post) {
  if (condition based on $post) $page_templates = 'path-to-template.php';
  return $page_templates;
  }
```

So, you can place the template file wherever you want and assign it when the page is in that certain category. No need to touch the url structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is where body tags are your best friend. I would add the category as a custom body tag using this function:

```
/*Add custom body tag for categories*/
add_filter( 'body_class', 'cat_body_class' );
function cat_body_class( $classes ) {
if (is_single()) {
 $category = get_the_category();
 $classes[] = ‘category-‘.$category[0]->slug;
}
 return $classes;
}
```

Then simply use that body tag to style the page :) You won't even have to add any new page template (unless those categories have WAY different design/layout, or completely different logic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Mayers. The page actually has a different layout, that is why I was trying to create a new page using the page-.....php that wordpress provide. How should apply the function in that case? Thanks